# Applescript is not able to open sheet within a numbers file

Tags: macos, applescript

I am new to Applescripts and am trying to open a Numbers file for further processing. However, for the life of me I can't get it to open a sheet. My script is below and I have verified that the sheet with that name actually exists. The error message I get is:

```
Please check the sheet name and try again.
```

The full code is as follows:

```
-- Specify document path and other details
set documentPath to "/Users/uday/Downloads/tmm.numbers" -- Replace with actual path
set sheetName to "elo"
set rangeString to "A2:E3"

-- Initialize error flag
set hasError to false

-- Open the document
try
    tell application "Numbers"
        tell document documentPath
            -- Check if sheet exists
            if not (exists sheet sheetName) then
                display dialog "Sheet \"" & sheetName & "\" not found in the document." & return & return & "Please check the sheet name and try again." buttons {"OK"} default button 1
                set hasError to true
            else
                tell sheet sheetName
                    -- Check if range exists
                    try
                        set rangeToCheck to range rangeString
                    on error error_message number error_number
                        display dialog "Error accessing range \"" & rangeString & "\":" & return & error_message buttons {"OK"} default button 1
                        set hasError to true
                    end try
                end tell
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
on error error_message number error_number
    display dialog "Error opening document \"" & documentPath & "\":" & return & error_message buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    set hasError to true
end try

-- Continue with your script if no errors occurred
if not hasError then
    -- Do something with the document, sheet, or range
    display dialog "Document, sheet, and range accessed successfully!" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument of `document` is either an index or the name of the document (the string in the title bar).

To open the document you have to call `open` and coerce the POSIX path to universal «class furl»

Then access the front document by index

```
-- Open the document
try
    tell application "Numbers"
        open documentPath as «class furl»
        tell document 1
            -- Check if sheet exists
```

Alternatively use a relative HFS path

```
set documentPath to (path to downloads folder as text) & "tmm.numbers"

...

tell application "Numbers"
    open documentPath
```

Edit: And as already mentioned by Mockman a `range` is an element of `table` which is an element of `sheet`. So either replace

```
tell sheet sheetName
```

with

```
tell table 1 of sheet sheetName
```

or replace

```
set rangeToCheck to range rangeString
```

with

```
set rangeToCheck to range rangeString of table 1
```

Comment: I tried the alternative option suggested by you and the file at least opens now. However, the error that comes next is:

Script Error
Numbers got an error: Can’t get range "A2:E3".

Comment: You have to provide the general structure to the script. A *range* is part of a *table* which is part of a *sheet*. Try `set rangeToCheck to range rangeString of table "Table 1"`

Comment: That was useful @Mockman and @vadian. The exact line that helped was `set dataRange to range "A2:E3" of "Table 1"`. However, the next error comes as `Can’t make \"A2:E3\" into type integer." number -1700 from "A2:E3" to integer` . Can you please help? It would be nice if you could also point me to a reliable reference, as I seem to be fixing literally one line at at time

Comment: Please ask a new question.